# Translating a foreign degree's name?

Tags: undergraduate, translations

I plan on obtaining a bachelor's degree at a Norwegian university in what is called "dataingeniør". In the future I'd like to continue my studies in a different country, so I'm going to need to know what to write in my CV.

A direct translation of "dataingeniør" would be "computer engineer", but my understanding is that that usually refers to hardware engineers in the English speaking world. The program I'm planning on taking is however strictly software as far as I can tell.

Is there anything wrong with simply calling it "computer science"? The program covers typical CS stuff like OS, algorithms, databases and programming, so I feel like they are equivalent.

Comment: Are you planning to go to industry or do a PhD? If it is the first, you should ask at the Workplace.SE, they should know better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made [a post on this matter a little while ago](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66013/translating-academic-cv-translate-names-of-papers-thesis) and just finished translating my CV, so I'll tell you what I did.

Leave the university name alone, don't translate it, UNLESS you think it would be unreadable by the folks who are reading your application (so if it was in Russian or Chinese for example). Does the name of your university look like something that would resemble 'university' in English? Leave it alone, or, if you have to, put it in quotations NEXT to the original university name. But do not remove or change the university's name, since it's a proper name.

In the case of "dataingeniør", leave that name there as well, and put in quotes the equivalent thing in your country. Same with the actual title of the degree e.g. B.Sc. Dataingeniør (equiv. Software Engineering Bachelors). Or you could put Computer Science if you feel it covered all the equivalent content (verified by a cursory glance at the CS programme information of the university for which you are applying). In any case, leave the title alone but then put in parentheses the equivalent qualification. And make sure it's actually equivalent (having a person from that country on hand to answer questions is important).

I was told also to not translate the name of project/thesis titles, UNLESS they are in a very hard-to-read language, and to go again with the quotes. But my advisor advised against this because it makes the CV 'look cluttered' and, according to him, it's not important unless the title uses a different character system.

Finally, if you are applying for a PhD, you should have a prospective advisor lined up, no? In that case, you can ask her/him or someone in her/his group to have a look over it for you, as it's in their best interest that you look good for the admissions team. Alternatively, somebody from the country should do.

Add a comment if you need to know something else. I just translated my entire CV so I'm happy to clarify additional stuff.

Comment: Thank you, that pretty much answers everything I was wondering about!